# Outlook Addin - How to send individual link to every attendee?

Tags: email, outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I would like to extend the logic of my Outlook Addin with the following feature :

When the appointment is sent by the organizer, i want every attendee to be able to have an **individual** link attached to his invitation.

**Example** :

Organizer adds the contacts a.a@aa.com, b.b@bb.com, c.c@cc.com to the appointment and sends it.

All attendees get the same appointment ( date, location, subject ), but

a.a@aa.com receives the link http://example.com/aaaaa,

b.b@bb.com receives the link http://example.com/bbbbb,

c.c@cc.com receives the link http://example.com/ccccc

It is not really relevant, where in the appointment ( body / subject / ...) the individual links are stored as long as every attendee becomes his individual link.

Is this possible at all using Outlook WebAddin Technology
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/) and if so, how?

Thank you and Best regards

Oliver

Comment: I posted an answer below that this is not supported currently. I'd like to know more about your scenario - what do you want the organizer/sender to see one of the recipient's content, all the recipient contents, or multiple calendar? Keep in mind that in a normal scenario, a single meeting request (with the same subject, body) is sent out all the recipients for a meeting.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the feature: customizing subject, body, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins

In general, this is something we probably wouldn't implement with add-ins. You may try a solution where you use EWS or Rest to send multiple different emails to individual recipients as a solution instead.